# Disable valid field coloring on Blazor InputSelect

Tags: validation, blazor, blazor-server-side

In an EditForm I've got an InputSelect dropdown list.

```
<InputSelect class="form-select" style="width: 10%" @bind-Value="@testInt">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</InputSelect>

@code {
    private int? testInt;
}
```

How to disable the border coloring after an item was chosen?

[image]

Comment: Edit the involved classes in your site.css.  You can see the involved classes by right-clicking in Chrome and choosing inspect. (usually have to do this 2x, one to inspect the page, the next to inspect the exact element).  First, try just removing `class="form-select"` from your component declaration.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 oh god, I missed completely to inspect the object. Thank you!

.valid.modified:not([type=checkbox]) is having the green outline by default!

Comment: If possible, select your answer as the correct one, so people can see that the question has been answered.

Comment: I just tried, the site told me that I can only accept my own answer after 2 days has passed. But wont forget to do that!

If you answer with that solution, I can mark your answer as solution too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class="form-select" is having a part in site.css

```
.valid.modified:not([type=checkbox]) {
    outline: 1px solid #26b050;
}
```

This governs the valid input, colors the outline of the InputSelect.

Solved with BennyBoy1973's suggestion.

Comment: Just an additional comment.  Bootstrap is mega-powerful and customizable.  It's probably worth spending a few days going through docs and so on:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/overview/   You can also download a lot of samples and so on there.